# Is token valication needed if Firebase client requests through GCP API Gateway?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-api-gateway

I know it is necessary if it is through AWS API gateway. Since firebase are from google,  and from [this article](https://medium.com/@chamaln/setting-up-firebase-token-authentication-with-gcp-api-gateway-1a68578c1eca), it seems unnecessary.[image]
I am tossing up between keeping everything within Google or routing via AWS.
Thank you.

Comment: Why would you route Google traffic through AWS? That would add several hops and increase round trip time, and route traffic off Google's internal backbone.

Comment: I also want to know what would you want to achieve here.

Comment: Because I am much more familiar with AWS and it seems Google API gateway is very new. It is also possible that I only use firebase for Auth and leave the rest to AWS -- but I try not to, that is where the tossing up from.